# RewriteRule in .htaccess matches the first instance of string but not the complete string

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm using RewriteRule in my .htaccess to do some 301 redirects on my Wordpress website. I noticed that if I have a RewriteRule that is a continuation of the same text as another rule, it always matches to the first rule. How can I fix this so it only matches the complete string?

First rule that works: `RewriteRule ^/?ulock https://biketoeverything.com/2018/06/18/the-u-lock-to-buy/ [L,R=301,NC]`

Second rule that always goes to the incorrect post (the one above): `RewriteRule ^/?ulockbracket https://biketoeverything.com/2018/04/24/attach-any-u-lock-to-your-bike/ [L,R=301,NC]`

Comment: Make sure to use anchors e.g. `^/?ulock/?$` and `^/? ulockbracket/?$`

Comment: Looks like that worked! Feel free to post it as the answer so I can give you the accepted answer (and upvote my question if you think it could be useful to others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have rule as:

```
RewriteRule ^/?ulock ...
RewriteRule ^/?ulockbracket ...
```

Then first pattern matches any URI that starts with `/ulock` which will also match `/ulockbracket` hence second rule will not fire.

Solution is to make sure to use regex anchors to ensure we use precise matching:

```
RewriteRule ^/?ulock/?$ https://biketoeverything.com/2018/06/18/the-u-lock-to-buy/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?ulockbracket/?$ https://biketoeverything.com/2018/04/24/attach-any-u-lock-to-your-bike/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

or **use longer matching pattern** before shorter matching one:

```
RewriteRule ^/?ulockbracket https://biketoeverything.com/2018/04/24/attach-any-u-lock-to-your-bike/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?ulock https://biketoeverything.com/2018/06/18/the-u-lock-to-buy/ [L,R=301,NC]
```